# Changing background Image based on Route in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, background-image, react-router-dom

Hey I have a background image for Home component. I've placed the background image in Header Component. In my Header component there is a navbar and the background image. I've place the Header component outside switch inside React Router so that some pages can access the navbar. Now what I want to do is when I go to a food description page I want to keep the navbar but I want to change/remove the background Image . How can I achieve that ?

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DataContextProvider>
        <LoginContextProvider>
          <Router>
            <Header></Header>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route path="/food/:id" component={FoodDetail} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </LoginContextProvider>
      </DataContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Header.js

```
<div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="fixed" style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <Container>
          <Toolbar>
            <Link to="/">
              <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
                Material-UI
              </Typography>
            </Link>

            <div className={classes.grow} />
            <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>
              {loggedInUser.email ? (
                <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="account of current user"
                    aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    color="inherit"
                  >
                    <AccountCircleIcon style={{ fill: "black" }} />
                  </IconButton>
                  <p className={classes.textColor}>{loggedInUser.name}</p>
                </MenuItem>
              ) : (
                <MenuItem onClick={handleLogin}>
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="account of current user"
                    aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    color="inherit"
                  >
                    <AccountCircleIcon style={{ fill: "black" }} />
                  </IconButton>
                  <p className={classes.textColor}>Login</p>
                </MenuItem>
              )}

              <IconButton
                aria-label="show 11 new notifications"
                color="inherit"
              >
                <Badge badgeContent={0} color="secondary">
                  <ShoppingCart style={{ fill: "black" }}></ShoppingCart>
                </Badge>
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.sectionMobile}>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="show more"
                aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
                color="inherit"
              >
                <MenuIcon style={{ fill: "black" }} />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </Toolbar>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMobileMenu}

      {renderMenu}
      <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bg})` }} className="header">
        <h2>Whatever you need, we will deliver it to you!</h2>
        <Paper component="form" className="search">
          <InputBase
            className={classes.input}
            placeholder="Search Keywords"
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search google maps" }}
            onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          />
          <IconButton
            type="submit"
            className={classes.iconButton}
            aria-label="search"
          >
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

FoodDetail.js

```
const FoodDetail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [foodDetails, setFoodDetails] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/foods/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setFoodDetails(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, [id]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Details</h1>
      <h1>Name: {foodDetails.name} </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use 'useLocation' to get the page path and then add it in a className.

**Header.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Header.css";

import Navigation from "../Navigation/Navigation";

export default function Header() {
  const path = useLocation().pathname;
  const location = path.split("/")[1];

  return (
    <div className={"header " + location}>
      <Navigation />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Header.css**

```
.header {
  height: 300px;
}
.header.home {
  background: grey
}
.header.about {
  background: red
}
.header.contact {
  background: yellow
}
```

**Check my complete demo** : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kcxqzh?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Thanks mate ! It worked but still have some issues . I have set a h2 and search bar over the home bg image . I've specified the component name in header.css but still in every page I can see the search bar and h2 tag . How can I solve this ? here's my gist link - https://gist.github.com/Fahim04blue/fe3fb89d5bc2202268dc9b83930c4f88

Comment: You want this h2 and search bar only in home page ?

Comment: Check my edited demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kcxqzh?file=src%2Fpages%2FContact%2FContact.js

Comment: Thanks man for the help . It works perfectly